# call variable inside the class

Tags: php, class

I have to call a variable inside a class. How can I?

page1.php

```
<?php

$conn = array('1','2','3');

?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php

class Test
{
//here i want the $conn variable
}

?>
```

Comment: Include `page1.php` on `page2.php`

Comment: It's not really OOP-style to use global scope variables. I advice using class properties or constants instead.

Comment: @Roopendra: but cannot access $conn inside the class. Plz  give me your answer.

Comment: Why must they be on separate pages? Either include or require it, or declare the variable in page2.php.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://php.net/oop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a.php

```
$conn = array('1','2','3');
```

You can include above page and
in your class:

```
include("a.php");
class Test
    {
        public $arr;
        function __construct($arr){
          $this->arr = $arr;

        }

    }
    $t1 = new Test($conn);//pass the array from above page in the class
    print_r($t1->arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

Comment: @deepus: Did you want this?

Answer (score 2):

Page1.php

```
$conn = array("1","2","3","4");
```

Page2.php

```
include 'Page1.php';

class Test {
    function __construct($var){
        $this->param = $var;
    }
}

$newTest = new Test($conn);
var_dump($newTest->param);
//prints the array $conn
```

Naturally you can rename the variables however you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access variable inside the class directly. you can use global variable scope

You can do like this as well:-

```
include 'page1.php';

class Test {

    public function test1() {
        global $conn;
        return $conn;
    }

}

$testObj = new Test;
print_r($testObj->test1());
```